# Problems installing scrypt-0.7.1 on Ubuntu into a virtual environment

Tags: 14.10, python-2.7, scrypt

I'm trying to install the python package *[scrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrypt/)* into my virutal python environment under Ubuntu. I don't quite understand the error message. What do I have to do in order to make it work?

```
nuc@nuc:~/Dropbox/julie$ source julie/bin/activate
(julie)nuc@nuc:~/Dropbox/Julie$ pip install scrypt
Collecting scrypt
/home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading scrypt-0.7.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scrypt
  Running setup.py install for scrypt
    Complete output from command /home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-utQ19_/scrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0_M4Md-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/include/site/python2.7/scrypt:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_scrypt' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6/lib
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6/lib/scryptenc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6/lib/util
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DHAVE_LIBRT=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO_MEM_UNIT=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO_TOTALRAM=1 -DHAVE_SYSINFO=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SYSINFO_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Iscrypt-1.1.6 -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/util -I/home/nuc/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c src/scrypt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/scrypt.o -O2
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DHAVE_LIBRT=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO_MEM_UNIT=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_SYSINFO_TOTALRAM=1 -DHAVE_SYSINFO=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SYSINFO_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Iscrypt-1.1.6 -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.1.6/lib/util -I/home/nuc/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c scrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto/crypto_aesctr.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto/crypto_aesctr.o -O2
    scrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto/crypto_aesctr.c:38:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
     #include <openssl/aes.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-utQ19_/scrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0_M4Md-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/nuc/Dropbox/julie/julie/include/site/python2.7/scrypt" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-utQ19_/scrypt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two error messages, two answers:

1. Simply run the command below to install the ssl development libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
   ```

   *Why?*

   From the error message:

   ```
   scrypt-1.1.6/lib/crypto/crypto_aesctr.c:38:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
   #include <openssl/aes.h>
   ```

   Where is `openssl/aes.h`?

   ```
   % apt-file search openssl/aes.h
   libssl-dev: /usr/include/openssl/aes.h
   ```
2. And the other error message

   ```
   /home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
     InsecurePlatformWarning
   ```

   Use this commands

   ```
   conda install cryptography
   pip install 'requests[security]'
   ```

   or use Python > 2.7.9

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't dependencies be included automatically? It worked. But I still got this warning: `/home/nuc/Dropbox/Julie/julie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning`

Comment: @empedokles answer updated

Comment: I guess I'm using anaconda. Would it help to run an update?

Comment: Try a `conda install cryptography` before `pip install 'requests[security]'`

Comment: @empedokles Updates are always a good idea =)